# what is the following oop structure here?

Tags: c++, oop, embedded, var

In the code below where is the variable, and where is the variable type? We have here properties of registers being changed.

If its an object oriented then we need an object name where we change its properties.

In here I don't see where is the type where is the variable name and how exactly we change its inner properties?

```
#include <stm32f0xx.h>

int main(void)
{
  RCC->AHBENR|=RCC_AHBENR_GPIOCEN ;
  GPIOC->MODER|=GPIO_MODER_MODERG_O ;
}
```

Comment: You have two global objects, `RCC` and `GPIOC`, declared in  `stm32fox.h`

Comment: Hello Thomas, what is the type of RCC and GPIOC ?
what kind of object are they?

Comment: I don't know. You didn't post the content of `stm32fox.h`

Comment: I understand so this objects are declared inside of STM32FOX.
Thank you very much

Comment: @rocko445 : Just open the header and take a look.  However it is stm32f0xx.h not stm32fox.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with OOP, it is just a structure member assignment.  `RCC` and `GPIOC` are defined in [stm32f0xx.h](http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/arm/st/stm32f0xx/stm32f0xx.h):

```
#define RCC                 ((RCC_TypeDef *) RCC_BASE)
```

and

```
#define GPIOC               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOC_BASE)
```

Where `RCC_BASE` and `GPIOC_BASE` are are defined in the same header as abaolute addresses, and  `RCC_TypeDef` and `GPIO_TypeDef` are structure types - for example:

```
typedef struct
{
  __IO uint32_t MODER;        /*!< GPIO port mode register,                                  Address offset: 0x00 */
  __IO uint16_t OTYPER;       /*!< GPIO port output type register,                           Address offset: 0x04 */
  uint16_t RESERVED0;         /*!< Reserved,                                                                 0x06 */
  __IO uint32_t OSPEEDR;      /*!< GPIO port output speed register,                          Address offset: 0x08 */
  __IO uint32_t PUPDR;        /*!< GPIO port pull-up/pull-down register,                     Address offset: 0x0C */
  __IO uint16_t IDR;          /*!< GPIO port input data register,                            Address offset: 0x10 */
  uint16_t RESERVED1;         /*!< Reserved,                                                                 0x12 */
  __IO uint16_t ODR;          /*!< GPIO port output data register,                           Address offset: 0x14 */
  uint16_t RESERVED2;         /*!< Reserved,                                                                 0x16 */
  __IO uint32_t BSRR;         /*!< GPIO port bit set/reset registerBSRR,                     Address offset: 0x18 */
  __IO uint32_t LCKR;         /*!< GPIO port configuration lock register,                    Address offset: 0x1C */
  __IO uint32_t AFR[2];       /*!< GPIO alternate function low register,                Address offset: 0x20-0x24 */
  __IO uint16_t BRR;          /*!< GPIO bit reset register,                                  Address offset: 0x28 */
  uint16_t RESERVED3;         /*!< Reserved,                                                                 0x2A */
}GPIO_TypeDef;
```

So expanding the macros in:

```
RCC->AHBENR|=RCC_AHBENR_GPIOCEN ;
```

resolves to:

```
((RCC_TypeDef*)0x40021000)->AHBENR |= ((uint32_t)0x00080000) ;
```

Where `0x40021000` is the base address of the RCC, an `AHBENR` refers to an RCC register to which the GPIOC enable flag is being set.

stm32f0xx.h defines structures for the register set of each peripheral, then defined macros that map the structure to the address at which each peripheral resides.